# Background music is not playing

Tags: c++, xcode, cocos2d-x

I have developed a game using cocos2d-x. I have a question about background music. When i press keyMenuClicked it is going to pause and i restart, background music is not playing.
I am using the following code in appdelegate.cpp

```
applicationDidEnterBackground()
{
CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->pauseBackgroundMusic();
}
applicationDidEnterforeground()
{
CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->resumeBackgroundMusic();
}
```

Comment: If you are playing around with the backgroundmusic volume set the background music volume to 10 in resume.  CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->setBackgroundMusicVolume(10);

Comment: Where do i need to use, in applicationdidenterforeground.

Comment: Test the volume in which method you resume the background music and let me know

Comment: applicationWillEnterForeground.

Comment: Paste the line which i gave you before for volume in applicationWillEnterForeground and give a try

Comment: If i press keymenuclick & restart it is playing from start, not resuming.

Comment: // This function will be called when the app is inactive. When comes a phone call,it's be invoked too
void AppDelegate::applicationDidEnterBackground() {
    //CCDirector::sharedDirector()->stopAnimation();
    // if you use SimpleAudioEngine, it must be pause
     SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->pauseBackgroundMusic();
}
// this function will be called when the app is active again
void AppDelegate::applicationWillEnterForeground() {
    //CCDirector::sharedDirector()->startAnimation();
    CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->resumeBackgroundMusic();
}

Comment: Just to test keep two buttons and create two method's one for resume and one for pause. Use the codes accordingly and test. Before that in init just set the volume to 10 and play the background music

Comment: Why is your provided code missing the `AppDelegate::` before each function?

Comment: Thanks for your answers. What you mentioned in above code is working.but there is a small issue. After installing, first time when i play, background music is going to pause but not resuming. It happens only first time.

Comment: Even quit is also not working for first time, if i press keymenuclick 2 times then i press quit its not working, game is restart 2 times.it is also happens in first time.